# how to measure TCL code coverage?

Tags: tcl, code-coverage

Does anyone know a tool or method used for measuring TCL code coverage?
I have tried google but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

The Active State Tcl DevKit has a debugger that can measure code coverage. You can look at ActiveState.com for details.

Comment: I believe that ActiveState's Komodo can also do code coverage, because it uses the TclDevKit internally.

Answer (score 2):

Try nagelfar. It works well for simple code coverage analysis. I had used it a couple of years back. However, it does not provide code coverage for Itcl I think.

(Don't be mislead by the initial description about the syntax checker. It provides code coverage also. )
http://nagelfar.berlios.de/